# Laravel 5 Eloquent ORM select where - array as parameter

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm getting grade_id from the database:

`$grade_id = DB::table('grades')->where('teacher_id',$teacher_id)->select('grade_id')->get();`

and then I want to use that grade_id array in the where eloquent clause so I run

```
$home_feed = Home::join('home_grade', 'home_grade.home_id', '=', 'homes.id')
                               ->whereIn('grade_id', $grade_id)
                               ->get();
```

but when I run this I'm getting an error: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

What could be the problem? Thanks guys.

Comment: Try `$grade_id = DB::table('grades')->where('teacher_id',$teacher_id)->select('grade_id')->first();`

Comment: Your first query probably returns collection object, so try `$grade_id = DB::table('grades')->where('teacher_id',$teacher_id)->select‌​('grade_id')->get()-‌​>lists('grade_id')->‌​all();` or  `DB::table('grades')->where('teacher_id',$teacher_id)->pluck('grade_id')->all()` then second query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on laravels version your `$grade_id` is either an array or a collection of objects. What you need is an array or a collection of values. 
You can achieve that using the `pluck()` method insted of `select()` like IzzEps suggested.

But you can get the same result by passing a subquery to the `whereIn()` method:

```
$gradeSubquery = DB::table('grades')->where('teacher_id',$teacher_id)->select('grade_id');

$home_feed = Home::join('home_grade', 'home_grade.home_id', '=', 'homes.id')
                 ->whereIn('grade_id', $gradeSubquery)
                 ->get();
```

This way you will run only one query instead of two.

**Update:** Before version 5.2 you have to use `lists()` instead of `pluck()`. And the `whereIn()` method doesn't accept a `Builder` as second parameter. To get the same query you would need to use a closure:

```
$home_feed = Home::join('home_grade', 'home_grade.home_id', '=', 'homes.id')
    ->whereIn('grade_id', function($query) use($teacher_id) {
        $query->from('grades')
            ->where('teacher_id', $teacher_id)
            ->select('grade_id');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: When I use the subquery I get the following error `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, object given`

Comment: What is your laravel version?

Comment: @user3714932 i tested the following code on 5.2.39: `$subQuery = DB::table('categories')->where('name', $catName)->select('id'); $products = App\Product::join('category_product as cp', 'cp.product_id', '=', 'products.id')->whereIn('category_id', $subQuery)->get();`. And it executes the following working query: `select * from \`products\` inner join \`category_product\` as \`cp\` on \`cp\`.\`product_id\` = \`products\`.\`id\` where \`category_id\` in (select \`id\` from \`categories\` where \`name\` = ?)`.

Comment: I'm using 5.0, maybe that's why

Comment: @user3714932 You're right - it's not supported before v5.2 :-( (just checked in laravels source code).

Answer (score 0):

your first query is returning a collection, not the grade_id.

Try this instead: `$grade_id = DB::table('grades')->where('teacher_id',$teacher_id)->pluck('grade_id');`

Comment: `Collection` isn't the problem. The problem is that it contains objects, while `whereIn()` needs an array/collection of simple values. But your code seems to be correct.

Comment: When I use pluck only one result (the first one) is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Using lists worked. 
`$grade_id = Grade::where('teacher_id', $teacher_id)->lists('grade_id');`
They return an array instead of a collection

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the array correctly. To do this use two functions that Eloquent work with: `pluck()` and `toArray()`. Look at example below:

```
$grade_id = DB::table('grades')->where('teacher_id',$teacher_id)->pluck('grade_id')->toArray();
```